# Trying to animate two UIViews simultaneously, only one moves

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to create an animation in my iOS app where a new view slides on screen from the left while the main view slides to the right to make room for it. The main view is a subview of my view controller's top view, and the side view that slides in is loaded from a separate xib file.

In case it's relevant, here's my code for loading the side view, called from my main view controller's viewDidLoad method:

```
sideViewController = [[SideViewController alloc] init];
[sideViewController loadView];

sideView = sideViewController.topView;
[self.view addSubview:sideView];
sideView.hidden = YES;
sideView.frame = CGRectMake(-200, 0, 200, 460);
```

And here's the code that gets called to animate the two views:

```
sideView.hidden = NO;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                 animations:^{                         
                     mainView.frame = CGRectMake(200, 0, 320, 460);
                     sideView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 460);
                 }];
```

This seems simple enough. But for some reason, only sideView animates -- mainView doesn't move anywhere. And to make things even more confusing, if I comment out the line in the animation block that moves sideView, the animation for mainView starts working.

Does anyone know what's wrong?  From all of the searches and docs I've read, what I'm doing ought to work fine. What I thought was going to be a simple animation has turned into hours of frustration. Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit:

Going off of Guo Luchuan's suggestion I tried animating different properties of the two UIViews. Most got the same result, though animating both of their transform properties *almost* worked. In that case both UIViews animated, but the mainView just did the wrong thing: its animation started with it in a different position and ended in the wrong place. It looks like it's performing the translation I instructed it to do, but starting at this position expressed in vector calculations:

```
starting_point - 0.5 * total_translation
```

meaning it ends at:

```
starting_point + 0.5 * total_translation
```

The sideView, however, animates correctly.

This is damned annoying. I didn't realize the performing animations on iOS in this way was so broken. The next thing I'm going to try is using CABasicAnimation, though I'm unhappy I have to resort to trying such a low level API for something so simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was I had autoresize turned on for my xib files. As soon as I turned it off, my original animation code worked flawlessly.

Comment: I had the same problem, and also had autoLayout on. Turning it off didn't help me any unfortunately.... although I might have missed the place where you turn it off globally (I am building my screens with code). One solution I found was to embed both views in a parent container view and just animate that.

Answer (score 4):

I have met a very same problem like you .

When I set 2 views same property (like `frame` or `transform`) at the same time , in the `UIView animation block` , it will not work for what I expect.

So , I set a views `frame` and set another views `transform` , then it works well , but I do not know why it will be that.

I think it will works fine for you.

```
sideView.hidden = NO;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                 animations:^{                         
                     mainView.frame = CGRectMake(200, 0, 320, 460);
                     sideView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(200,0);
                 }];
```

And I think you can make 2 `CABasicAnimation` and then add them into the `CAAnimationGroup`. It also can work for you

Comment: This is a great suggestion, though I gave it a try and it didn't work. I've actually tried animating several different combinations of attributes and either got the same result, or a different wrong result. I'm going to edit my main post to go into more detail about.

Answer (score 0):

If the `sideView` is a **subview** of `mainView`, use this animation method:

```
+animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
```

with option:

```
UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent
```

Comment: sideView and mainView are siblings underneath my view controller's top view, so this shouldn't apply. However, the strange thing is sideView is clearly affecting mainView in some weird way I don't understand, so I tried using this option anyway, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Sorry, I read your Q wrong. If they are siblings, I don't know what's happening to you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, and I think it's pretty heinous. Here's the code that works:

```
mainView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(400,0);
CABasicAnimation *move = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x" ];
[move setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:200]];
[move setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:400]];
[move setDuration:0.25];
move.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
[[mainView layer] addAnimation:move forKey:@"transform.translation.x"];

sideView.center = CGPointMake(100, 230);
CABasicAnimation *sideMove = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x" ];
[sideMove setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-200]];
[sideMove setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0]];
[sideMove setDuration:0.25];
sideMove.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
[[sideView layer] addAnimation:sideMove forKey:@"transform.translation.x"];
```

First, if I didn't set the mainView's transform, this whole thing wouldn't work and the mainView wouldn't move anywhere after the animation was done. I tried setting its frame and center, but neither had any effect. Only transform worked. This detail is similar to using the animateWithDuration method.

Second, and this is the part that has me the most confused, why are the numbers what they are? For whatever reason, I needed to offset the mainView by 200 extra pixels to the right (the width of sideView) in order to get it to line up properly. If I didn't do that, it would animate to exactly where it used to be, even though I was changing its affine transformation from identity to a translation 200 pixels to the right.

As near as I can tell, sideView is affecting mainView in some weird way, even though they are *siblings* directly under my view controller's top level view, and shouldn't have any kind of hierarchical relationship. My guess is this has something to do with loading the sideView from a xib, but as far as I can tell, I'm doing that correctly.

Hopefully this solution will be useful for someone else that finds themselves in a similar situation, and they won't have to do the same annoying dead chicken programming I just did.

Also, if anyone can offer an explanation for all of this, I would be very appreciative! I don't like coding things that I don't understand, and I'd love to learn why all of this happened so I can avoid situations like this in the future.

Comment: The real Q is, **why** it didn't work the simple way? If you can tell me some more things: From where are calling the animation? Are you using autoresizing or Auto Layout in code and XIB?

Comment: Oh dear god, the whole problem was that I had autolayout turned on. This isn't the first time I've made that mistake, but I forgot about it until you mentioned it. I just turned it off on both of my xib files and all of a sudden animateWithDuration works perfectly. Hours of my time were just lost because of that feature, and there was no indication that it was the culprit.

Comment: Yes, when using Auto Layout, you don't modify the frames directly. I didn't try animations under Auto Layout, but maybe you can animate `constant` of constraints.

Comment: @GuyGizmo thank you so much for finding that! an hour and half wasted here!